# Globals and Locals

Tags: lua, scope, global-variables, local-variables

I am sorry if this is a very basic question, but I am a beginner and am having issues with differentiating between local and global variables. For example:

```
variable=0
local variable=0
function func()
    local variable=0
    variable=0
    if variable==0 then
        local variable=1
    end
end
```

- How many separate variables do I have?
- Which variable is being reassigned in the if statement block? Or is it a new variable separate from all the others?
- Which variable is the if statement testing for?
- How do I set a new value to the 1st local variable in the function inside my if statement block? Would that not be just instantiating a new variable limited to the if statement block?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (1) How many separate variables do I have?

Four: three locals and one global. Though a 'global variable' is simply a field in the function's environment (`_G`).

> (2) Which variable is being reassigned in the if statement block? Or is it a new variable separate from all the others?

Creating a new variable, shadowing the ones further up the stack.

> (3) Which variable is the if statement testing for?

The second `local` one, defined right after `function func()`

> (4) How do I set a new value to the 1st local variable in the function inside my if statement block?

You'd have to set it before you define a new `local` that shadows the old one. After that, it's impossible (except maybe with the debug library).

Here's your example, with some values edited and some print statements, to demonstrate scoping rules in Lua:

```
variable=123
print(variable) -- prints 123
local variable=0
print(variable) -- prints 0
function func()
    local variable=1
    variable=1
    print(variable) -- prints 1
    if variable==1 then
        print(variable) -- prints 1
        local variable=5
        print(variable) -- prints 5
    end
    print(variable) -- prints 1
end
func()
print(variable) -- prints 0
print(_G.variable) -- prints 123
```

Comment: `func` is a fifth variable, presumably global.